# curl to java conversion

Tags: java, php, curl

I'm trying to translate a POST request that i made in php to Java. The request is based on curl. I can make a request using GET method but when i try to switch to the POST method it doesn't work...

Here is the php request, all authentication variables and data are initialized before:

```
$curl = curl_init ();
curl_setopt_array ($curl, array (
  CURLOPT_URL => $site_url
  CURLOPT_USERPWD => $site_public_key . ":" . $site_private_key,
  CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => 1,
  CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST => "POST",
  CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS => $post_data
 ));

$data = curl_exec ($curl);

if ($data === false)
{
  echo 'Error: ' . curl_error ($curl);
}

else
{
  echo 'Result: ' . $data;
}


curl_close ($curl);
```

and here my Java version, all authentication variables and data are initialized before:

```
try
{

    String site_authentication = site_public_key + ":" + site_private_key;
    String encoded_site_authentication = new String(new Base64().encode(site_authentication.getBytes())).replaceAll("[\n\r]", "");

    URL url = new URL (resource_uri);
    HttpURLConnection connection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
    DataOutputStream dataOutputStream = null;
    connection.setRequestMethod("POST");  
    connection.setRequestProperty("Authorization", "Basic " +  encoded_site_authentication);
    connection.setDoOutput(true);
    connection.setReadTimeout(10000);
    connection.connect();
    connection.getInputStream();
    OutputStream output=connection.getOutputStream();
    output.write(post_data.getBytes());

    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
    String line = null;


    BufferedReader rd = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(connection.getInputStream()));
while ((line = rd.readLine()) != null) {
     sb.append(line);
}
    result = sb.toString();

}
catch (Exception e)
{
    e.printStackTrace();
}
out.println(result);
```

Something doesn't work... I think the problem is on the output stream, but i can't find the error

Thanks for help

Mr_Leo

Comment: You are much better off using [apache httpclient](http://hc.apache.org/httpcomponents-client-ga/) instead of rolling your own solution based on `java.net.URL`.

Comment: `new String` without a charset is a bad idea, as it will use the system's default charset.  If you are running on a Windows machine, for instance, your default charset is almost certainly UTF-16LE, which will result in a String with one character for every *two* bytes in your byte array.  On other systems the default charset is probably UTF-8, which will result in many malformed encodings.